# Генерация статического HTML на основе шаблонов

Tags: html, шаблоны

В чем суть. Нужно сделать статический сайт-визитку (для того чтобы можно было выкладывать на бесплатный хостинг, да и в принципе динамика там не нужна, разве что для удобства).

Информация будет добавлятся и редактироваться, но редко и хотелось бы чтобы у человека был инструмент, с помощью которого он мог что-то подправить в контенте но при этом не лезть в оформление.

Как я себе это вижу: есть файлик template и content, дальше из консоли выполняем комманду, приложение прочитает template и опеределенные места заменит соответсвующими фрагмантами из content и формирует generated-template.html (ну и желательно чтобы элементарно хотя бы for был).

В принципе написать такое прилжоение не сильно сложно, можно взять java, themeleaf, jackson и за пару часов сделать. Но может есть что-то готовое?

Comment: а jekill или octopres не вариант ?

Comment: А что позволяет этот бесплатный хостинг? Только статичные файлы хранить? PHP+MySQL (например) он точно не предоставляет?

Comment: Это так и называется - генератор статических сайтов, таких навалом на любой вкус (я юзаю pelican)